# Buffered writes for UNIX sockets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, io

I'm opening a socket to send requests directly to the X server (to bypass using Xlib/XCB).

```
#define X11_OP_REQ_CREATE_WINDOW  0x01
#define X11_OP_REQ_MAP_WINDOW     0x08
#define X11_OP_REQ_CREATE_PIX     0x35
#define X11_OP_REQ_CREATE_GC      0x37
#define X11_OP_REQ_PUT_IMG        0x48

...

  struct sockaddr_un serv_addr = {0};
  int socketfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  // Create the socket!
  serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcopy(serv_addr.sun_path, "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0", 0);
  int srv_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
  connect(socketfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

I must do a bunch of `write()`s, though, and I know that for files this can be a lot slower than `fwrite`, due to buffering, since syscalls are expensive. Is there an equivalent function that works with sockets?. Is it even possible to do buffered IO with sockets? (Nevermind that `fwrite` needs a `FILE*` stream too, and all I have is a descriptor.)

Here's an example of a function that sends such a request (using `write`).

```
void x11_put_img(int socketfd, struct x11_connection* conn, uint8 format, uint32 target, uint32 gc, uint16 w, uint16 h, uint16 x, uint16 y, uint8 depth, uint32* data){
    uint32 packet[6];
    uint16 length = ((w*h)) + 6;

    packet[0] = X11_OP_REQ_PUT_IMG | format<<8 | length<<16;
    packet[1] = target;
    packet[2] = gc;
    packet[3] = w | h<<16;
    packet[4] = x | y<<16;
    packet[5] = depth<<8;

    write(socketfd, packet, 24);
    write(socketfd, data, (w*h)*4);

    return;
}
```

(No error checking, for simplicity.)

Comment: Not sure how you think that would work. Normally if you send something through a socket, you expect a reply before sending the next command. With buffered writes, you also had buffered reads and some kind of message queueing. Not sure if that's really worth the overhead.

Comment: [writev](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readv.2.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *are* doing buffered writes, albeit a bit incorrectly.  When you call, for example,

```
    write(socketfd, packet, 24);
```

what do you think `packet` is?

Now, you can create a larger buffer, say `unsigned char buffer[4096]`, then `memcpy()` your output into it and eventually `write()` larger chunks of data at a time.  That makes sense only up to a point however, for if you need to also receive *responses* to the messages you send then there's no advantage to breaking up the transmission other than at message boundaries (unless messages are exceedingly long), and it will complicate your code to buffer more than one message before sending.

Be aware, however, that `write()` does not guarantee to send the whole number of bytes requested.  Its return value tells you how many it actually did send, and in the event of a short write you probably need to call `write()` one or more additional times to send the rest of the bytes.

You do have the option of putting most of that on the C library by wrapping the socket file descriptor in a stream via `fdopen()`, and using the stream I/O functions.  In that case, you can configure buffering details via `setvbuf()`.

Comment: I just tried using `fdopen` with `fwrite` and it was much slower. I guess I'll stick to `write`. Thanks!

Comment: @étale-cohomology - John's answer is very succinct and includes important advice. As he points out, `write` might send only **some** of the data (but not all of it) - something you are less likely to experience when testing locally. In some cases, slower might be safer... I implemented a user land buffer with locking for [facil.io](http://facil.io), it's obviously slower, but it's better than unexpected data loss.